# Using PUT verb in edit form using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Restful Routing .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, restful-url

I'm using the Restful Routing .NET NuGet package (https://github.com/stevehodgkiss/restful-routing) in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project.  According to the documentation, I should be able to submit a form using the PUT verb to the Update action in a controller by placing the `@HTML.PutOverrideTag()` in the form.  I have not been able to get this to work.  Every time I submit the form I get a 404 Not Found error.  Can anyone confirm whether they have been able to get this working properly? My code is below:

routeconfig.cs:

```
map.Resources<UsersController>();
```

views\users\edit.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("update", "users", new { id = Model.Id }))
{
    @Html.PutOverrideTag()

    <input id="user_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

UsersController.cs:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var user = UserRepository.GetById(id);
    return View(user);
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult Update(int id, User user)
{
    return View("edit", user);
}
```

Steps to recreate:

1. Browse to: /user/edit
2. Form displays
3. Press submit button
4. Receive 404 Not Found error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Put)
```

instead of

```
@Html.PutOverrideTag()
```

Comment: This is best thing I've found all day!  Never even knew this existed!